# Element by element tensor multiplication in python

Tags: math, set, algebra, tensor

I am trying to solve a problem in computational algebra using python.

Basically given two sets, say `A={a,b}` and `B={e}`, I need to compute the element by element tensor products and get a final set say `C={a\tensor{e},b\tensor{e}}`  containing these products of elements.

I can do an element by element multiplication using arrays with numbers but I can't do an element by element tensor multiplication of letters instead of numbers.

Comment: Are you looking into tensors that can have _any_ rank? you can use chars like `'a','b'` perhaps

Comment: All the tensors I am using are simple i.e of rank 1, and the tensor products will always be between two elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly, this below code multiplies each letter of one set with each letter of the the other set

```
def getProduct(A,B):
    prod=[]
    for a in A:
        for b in B:
           prod.append(a+b)
    return prod

A=['a','b']
B=['e']
print(getProduct(A,B))

Output: ['ae', 'be']
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thank you.

Comment: @Kalya if it answered your question, you could 'accept' it