# Row wise Tensor multiplication

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensor

Let say we have two 2D tensors

`A = [[a, b], [c, d]]` and, `B=[[e, f], [g, h]]`

I need a 1D tensor with values `[ae + bf + ce + df, ag + ah + cg + ch]`

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328299/element-by-element-tensor-multiplication-in-python) for the logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

A=[[1, 2], [3, 4]]

B=[[5, 6], [7, 8]]

Ax = tf.Variable(initial_value=A)

Bx = tf.Variable(initial_value=B)

with tf.Session() as sess :
    sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
    ABx = tf.tensordot(Ax, Bx, axes=[[1], [1]])
    print(sess.run( tf.reduce_sum(ABx, 0) ))
```

`ABx = tf.tensordot(Ax, Bx, axes=[[1], [1]])` gives  you this.

```
[[17 23]
 [39 53]]
```

`tf.reduce_sum(ABx, 0)` gives you this.

```
[56 76]
```

The code `tf.reduce_sum(tf.matmul(Ax, Bx,transpose_b=True),0)` gives the same result too.